# Error: Unsupported argument terraform ecs with load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, aws-application-load-balancer

appreciate your support in solving this issue i have main.tf file like below

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "nodejs-service" {
  name            = "nodejs-service"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.project_cluster.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.nodejs.arn
  launch_type     = "FARGATE"
  desired_count   = 1

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arns = module.alb.target_group_arns
    container_name   = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.nodejs.family}"
    container_port   = 8080 # Specifying the container port
  }

  network_configuration {
    subnets          = var.vpc.public_subnets
    assign_public_ip = true
  }
}

module "alb" {
  source             = "terraform-aws-modules/alb/aws"
  version            = "~> 8.0"
  name               = var.namespace
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  vpc_id             = var.vpc.vpc_id
  subnets            = var.vpc.public_subnets
  security_groups    = [var.sg.lb]

  http_tcp_listeners = [
    {
      port               = 80
      protocol           = "HTTP"
      target_group_index = 0
    }
  ]

  target_groups = [
    { name_prefix      = "nodejs-service"
      backend_protocol = "HTTP"
      backend_port     = 8080
      target_type      = "instance"
    }
  ]
}
```

i receive error

```
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on modules/ecs/main.tf line 58, in resource "aws_ecs_service" "nodejs-service":
│   58:     target_group_arns = module.alb.target_group_arns
│
│ An argument named "target_group_arns" is not expected here. Did you mean "target_group_arn"?
```

even if i changed target_groups on the service parameters to be target_group_arn i receive error "target_group_arn" is not defined
also with module.alb.target_groups[0] the same error appear with terraform plan

```
  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn   = module.alb.target_groups[0]
    container_name   = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.nodejs.family}"
    container_port   = 8080 # Specifying the container port
  }
```

Error:

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on modules/ecs/main.tf line 58, in resource "aws_ecs_service" "nodejs-service":
   58:     target_group_arn   = module.alb.target_groups[0]
     ├────────────────
     │ module.alb is a object

 This object does not have an attribute named "target_groups".
```

as per main.tf file how can i select the target group which is defined in alb module

Thanks,

tried: terraform plan and expected alb with target group pointing on nodejs-service container

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0"

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = ">= 4.27"
    }
    null = {
      source  = "hashicorp/null"
      version = ">= 2.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: " if i changed target_groups on the service parameters" - what do you mean? Please add the code with that change and FULL error message.

Comment: `"target_group_arns"` option was added in terraform aws provider 2.22

Comment: @AhmedOmar can you add the exact module version, terraform version, as well as terraform provider for AWS version?

Comment: @MarkoE done updated in post module version was 5 then i changed to 8 and run it with the new module version and terraform 4.27

Comment: @AhmedOmar Did you run `terraform init` after changing the version?

Comment: @MarkoE yes, as you can see https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-alb/blob/master/examples/complete-alb/outputs.tf so it should accept my output `target_group_arns` but still same error, is it possible to simulate this main.tf with a simple task definition from your side? and thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not in the module, rather in the argument you are trying to use in the `aws_ecs_service` resource. You are currently setting it to `target_group_arns` while the argument is singular, i.e., `target_group_arn` [1]:

```
  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = module.alb.target_group_arns[0]
    container_name   = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.nodejs.family}"
    container_port   = 8080 # Specifying the container port
  }
```

The example is with the first of the target groups returned from the module, so make sure you are using the correct one.

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_service#target_group_arn

Comment: done but now i receive this ` module.alb is a object`  `This object does not have an attribute named "target_group".`

Comment: You have copied and pasted the above verbatim?

Comment: i copied it now and it works finally, thanks a lot @MarkoE

Answer (score 1):

output from the module alb is an array.

In your case it would be `module.alb.target_group_arns[0]`

Replace it with this code

```
load_balancer {
    target_group_arns = module.alb.target_group_arns[0]
    container_name   = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.nodejs.family}"
    container_port   = 8080 # Specifying the container port
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Jatin for your answer, now i receive the following error
This object does not have an attribute named "target_groups".

Comment: `│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on modules/ecs/main.tf line 58, in resource "aws_ecs_service" "nodejs-service":
│   58:     target_group_arns = module.alb.target_group_arns[0]
│
│ An argument named "target_group_arns" is not expected here. Did you mean "target_group_arn"?
`

Comment: Check your terraform aws provider version, I suppose it is an old version. If its old version try `target_group_arn` for ecs resource. Even in the example code its target_group_arn `load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.foo.arn
    container_name   = "mongo"
    container_port   = 8080
  }
`https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_target_group#attributes-reference

Comment: the service can't access the target group on alb module, sorry im new with terraform so i apply some tasks from terraform-in-action book
[link](https://github.com/terraform-in-action/manning-code/tree/master/chapter4/complete)
 but with ecs fargate not normal ec2

Comment: Why are using such old version? any specific reason? the current version of module uses 8.0 `version = "~> 8.0"`
Try reading this gothic readme, https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-alb/tree/v8.3.1

Comment: i did and changed the version to 8.0 and aws provider to 4 but still same issue anyway i created new alb resource and now it works

Comment: If you think my answer would help someone in the future, do upvote it so that it my may help others in the future

Comment: i need 15 reputation so i can upvote